# Some htaccess 301 redirects not matching the right rule

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection

I am trying to redirect some links from an old WordPress website to the new one.

My .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^press-release-mcp-and-tmr-integrate-to-seize-maritime-communications-opportunities$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-mcp-and-tmr-integrate-to-seize-maritime-communications-opportunities [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-release-bygger-verdens-storste-4g-nett-offshore$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-bygger-verdens-storste-4g-nett-offshore [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-release-33-cruise-ships-with-mobile-and-internet-services-from-mcp$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-33-cruise-ships-with-mobile-and-internet-services-from-mcp [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-release-mcp-to-install-4g-infrastructure-on-norwegian-continental-shelf-with-shell$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-mcp-to-install-4g-infrastructure-on-norwegian-continental-shelf-with-shell [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-release-returns-to-win-offshore$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-returns-to-win-offshore [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^can-it-be-true-that-todays-improvements-in-communication-for-the-offshore-environment-initiate-a-paradigm-shift$ http://newurl.com/news/can-it-be-true-that-todays-improvements-in-communication-for-the-offshore-environment-initiate-a-paradigm-shift [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^how-mobile-data-roaming-increases-your-mobile-data-traffic$ http://newurl.com/news/how-mobile-data-roaming-increases-your-mobile-data-traffic [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^why-is-improved-personalized-communication-paramount-for-the-offshore-industry$ http://newurl.com/news/why-is-improved-personalized-communication-paramount-for-the-offshore-industry [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^why-mobile-data-will-remain-the-most-important-source-of-revenue$ http://newurl.com/news/why-mobile-data-will-remain-the-most-important-source-of-revenue [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^color-line-extends-contract-with-mcp$ http://newurl.com/news/color-line-extends-contract-with-mcp [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^author/mcp$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^author/andreas-lutebergetmcp-com$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^author/roar-walderhaugmcp-com$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^archives/press-releases$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^archives/news$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^archives/insights$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^need-for-offshore-speed$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^customers$ http://newurl.com/service-support [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-mcp/travel-smart$ http://newurl.com/service-support [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-mcp/organization$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/the-team [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-mcp/career$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/careers [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-mcp$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^cruise$ http://newurl.com/business/cruise [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ferry$ http://newurl.com/business/ferry [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fisheries$ http://newurl.com/business/fisheries [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^solutions$ http://newurl.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^offshore$ http://newurl.com/business/offshore [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/contact [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^history$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/history [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^installations-in-operation$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/installations-in-operation [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mcp-insight$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^newsevents$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^protu_roaming.php$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/installations-in-operation [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^coverage.php$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/installations-in-operation [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-kit$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newurl.com [L,R=301]
```

Some old links redirect correctly to the new ones as the rule specify (cruise, about-mcp, history), but others are just matching to the last rule (the first 16 rules; from "press-release-mcp-and-tmr..." to "archives/insights").

Every htaccess tester I tried said that the rules are ok (http://htaccess.mwl.be/, http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) but when I try with a browser or with curl, they don't.

Any idea how I can fix this?

**UPDATE**

Those that work:

```
RewriteRule ^need-for-offshore-speed$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^customers$ http://newurl.com/service-support [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-mcp/travel-smart$ http://newurl.com/service-support [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-mcp/organization$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/the-team [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-mcp/career$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/careers [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about-mcp$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^cruise$ http://newurl.com/business/cruise [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ferry$ http://newurl.com/business/ferry [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fisheries$ http://newurl.com/business/fisheries [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^solutions$ http://newurl.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^offshore$ http://newurl.com/business/offshore [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/contact [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^history$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/history [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^installations-in-operation$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/installations-in-operation [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mcp-insight$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^newsevents$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^protu_roaming.php$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/installations-in-operation [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^coverage.php$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/installations-in-operation [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-kit$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newurl.com [L,R=301]
```

Those that don't work:

```
RewriteRule ^press-release-mcp-and-tmr-integrate-to-seize-maritime-communications-opportunities$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-mcp-and-tmr-integrate-to-seize-maritime-communications-opportunities [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-release-bygger-verdens-storste-4g-nett-offshore$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-bygger-verdens-storste-4g-nett-offshore [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-release-33-cruise-ships-with-mobile-and-internet-services-from-mcp$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-33-cruise-ships-with-mobile-and-internet-services-from-mcp [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-release-mcp-to-install-4g-infrastructure-on-norwegian-continental-shelf-with-shell$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-mcp-to-install-4g-infrastructure-on-norwegian-continental-shelf-with-shell [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^press-release-returns-to-win-offshore$ http://newurl.com/news/press-release-returns-to-win-offshore [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^can-it-be-true-that-todays-improvements-in-communication-for-the-offshore-environment-initiate-a-paradigm-shift$ http://newurl.com/news/can-it-be-true-that-todays-improvements-in-communication-for-the-offshore-environment-initiate-a-paradigm-shift [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^how-mobile-data-roaming-increases-your-mobile-data-traffic$ http://newurl.com/news/how-mobile-data-roaming-increases-your-mobile-data-traffic [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^why-is-improved-personalized-communication-paramount-for-the-offshore-industry$ http://newurl.com/news/why-is-improved-personalized-communication-paramount-for-the-offshore-industry [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^why-mobile-data-will-remain-the-most-important-source-of-revenue$ http://newurl.com/news/why-mobile-data-will-remain-the-most-important-source-of-revenue [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^color-line-extends-contract-with-mcp$ http://newurl.com/news/color-line-extends-contract-with-mcp [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^author/mcp$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^author/andreas-lutebergetmcp-com$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^author/roar-walderhaugmcp-com$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^archives/press-releases$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^archives/news$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^archives/insights$ http://newurl.com/business/about-us/news-events [L,R=301]
```

Comment: separate those that work and post does that don't work

Comment: updated the question

Comment: your new urls with news are redirected as well to the url without news, maby this is interfering with these roules

Comment: the htaccess file redirects from oldurl.com to newurl.com. the urls are different.

Comment: Try this rule: `RewriteRule ^press-release-mcp-to-install-4g-infrastructure-on-norwegian-continental-shelf-with-shell$ http://newurl.com/press-release/press-release-mcp-to-install-4g-infrastructure-on-norwegian-continental-shelf-with-shell [L,R=301]`

Comment: tried it and not working... it matches the last rule.

Comment: without the last rule do the other rules work?

Answer (score -1):

One part of the problem could be [this](http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/), permanent redirect are cached by the browsers (and not, private mode doesn't help in the case of Google Chrome).

Another thing that I've discovered (having the advantage of knowing both the original URL and the new one) is that on Firefox (on private mode) the old URL is no longer redirected (badly) and it just throws a 404 (because the bad redirects have been deleted from the .htaccess file). This makes me think of the problem as being a caching one, even more.

These are my findings so far, I don't think the problem should be looked at from another perspective since for fresh systems doesn't have the same behaviour as tested environments.

I would honestly be glad to see a better answer than this one, if there will be any at all :)